# How to export data in the terminal to a file (e.g. csv file)

Tags: sed, grep, csv, spreadsheet

I am a complete beginner in using Linux and I would like to know how to export a bunch of data in the command line to a csv or spreadsheet file (or even text would work). Right now I am simply using `echo` on a topic that prints out a ton of data. So I can see the data as it streams over time. What I want to do is to section off only the parts with numbers and export them to a data file.

So for example if the command is repeatedly streaming something like:

```
header: 
  seq: 93342 
  stamp: 
    secs: 1406820172 
    nsecs: 191358647 
  frame_id: '' 
name: ['arm_joint_1', 'arm_joint_2', 'arm_joint_3', 'arm_joint_4', 'arm_joint_5', 'gripper_finger_joint_l', 'gripper_finger_joint_r'] 
position: [2.116426527797216, 1.8058519002096407, -1.6111500844302575, 3.479512978878036, 2.8513271915116376, 0.0, 0.0] 
velocity: [-0.0, -0.0, 0.0, -0.0, -0.0, 0.0, 0.0] 
effort: [] 
--- 
header: 
  seq: 93343 
  stamp: 
    secs: 1406820172 
    nsecs: 211357280 
  frame_id: '' 
name: ['arm_joint_1', 'arm_joint_2', 'arm_joint_3', 'arm_joint_4', 'arm_joint_5', 'gripper_finger_joint_l', 'gripper_finger_joint_r'] 
position: [2.116426527797216, 1.8058519002096407, -1.6111500844302575, 3.479512978878036, 2.8513271915116376, 0.0, 0.0] 
velocity: [-0.0, -0.0, 0.0, -0.0, -0.0, 0.0, 0.0] 
effort: []
```

etc, as time goes on, I want just the following:

1. The numbers representing Position and
2. The numbers representing Secs and Nsecs,

all in a csv file. The numbers are whatever they are and I have no way of knowing what this topic will be spitting out in advance.

A secondary question is, is there a way for it to simply export all of these numbers for as long as it is streaming, or do I have to stream for a few seconds, and then run a command to grab all the numbers that it spits out after the fact?

Comment: I have found that I can use grep to take for example, the line with just the positions, by piping to "grep positions: " But what about grep-ing for a particular line, and then using sed to replace strings? Can I do both commands in one line?

Answer (score 2):

The question has been edited to include data in a totally different format. The original answer is below the line, and the parts of it relating to `sed` in general still apply.

[`sed` can rewrite lines into other formats](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html). Here's a quick `sed` command to give you a CSV line per record for this new data:

```
sed -n -e '/secs:/{s/.*secs://;H;};/position:/{s/^.*position: \[\([^]]*\)\]/\1/;G;s/\n\+/,/gp}'
```

This uses the [hold space](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-h-_0028hold_0029-command-160). On the other hand, **what you really want here is a [YAML](http://www.yaml.org/) parser**; just because we can do it with `sed` or other tools doesn't mean we should.

To do a replacement and a grep at the same time with `sed`, you can use [`-n`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-g_t_002dn-6) and [`p`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-Text_002c-printing-after-substitution-113):

```
sed -n -e 's/foo/bar/p'
```

As for reading data as long as it's streaming, you can use [shell pipelines](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_02) to do this:

```
yourcommand | sed -e '...'
```

This puts the output of `yourcommand` straight into `sed`'s input, where it can process the vector fields out for you as above. When `yourcommand` finishes so does the pipeline.

To redirect the `sed` output into a file too you can use [output redirection](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07):

```
yourcommand | sed -e '...' > vectors.csv
```

This will make a CSV file called `vectors.csv` with the output of your `sed` command.

---

Given a file `data` in your (original) format:

```
time position t x: [0.1 1]
time position t x: [0.2 2]
time position t x: [0.3 3]
```

you could run:

```
sed -e 's/.*\[\([^]]*\)\].*/\1/' data
```

and get output of the form:

```
0.1 1
0.2 2
0.3 3
```

You might want this comma-separated, so we can do that too:

```
sed -e 's/.*\[\([^ ]*\) \([^]]*\)\].*/\1,\2/' < data

0.1,1
0.2,2
0.3,3
```

`sed` provides a programming language for rewriting lines, and we're using its `s` command to do a string replacement on the [regular expression](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03) that describes the entire line.

The pattern is between the first and second `/` characters. We have `.*` on the outside, to match the rest of the line (which we're going to throw away, but we need to address somewhere).

We match `[` and `]` as the edges of what we care about, and the two numbers inside them. Because the regular expression syntax also uses `[]` to mean something, we put backslashes before the ones we want literally. Those are right inside the `.*`s.

In between `\( \)` we're capturing text we match there. In this case that text is described by the expression `[^ ]*`, which means lots of any characters except a space. Then we do match a literal space from your data, followed by another capturing group. The second group matches `[^]]*`, which means lots of any characters except a `]`. Finally, we match the terminating `]` with `\]`.

The part between the second and third `/` is the replacement string, and we can refer to our two captured groups as `\1` and `\2` in there: `\1` becomes `0.1` and `\2` becomes `1` for the first line, for example. Any other characters are included literally in the output, so the separating comma appears in between them.

---

Comment: In the more complicated format that I changed the question to, I could see that certain characters would be complicated to get rid of, like ' and : and _ and [. I would definitely be grateful to get some help on how to delete those.

Comment: Your new data is so dissimilar that this isn't the same question any more. I have edited in a `sed` script that does it, but what you really want is a YAML parser. (You should also include data that is actually representative of what you want to start with)

Answer (score 0):

Try

`df -h | sed 's/[ \t]/,/g'`

or

`df -h | sed 's/[ \t]/,/g'`